# How to retrieve db2 rows using partial columns of compound key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, db2

I have a DB2 table with a compound unique key.

I have a compound key java class annotated as Embeddable. This "key" class is mentioned in my java entity java class as EmbeddedId.

Queries using the full compound key "findByPrimaryKey" work fine.

However i also need to retrieve all rows using only the first column of the compound key.

I would like to use the `org.hibernate.Criteria;` API to achieve this.

All my attempts so far have either retrieved no rows or all the rows from the entire table.

What is the correct way to employ a partial set of columns from a full compound key to retrieve a set of rows using hibernate?

Why cant i just create an `org.hibernate.criterion.Example` with the partial compound key attributes set? Hibernate seems to ignore `@Id` columns when they are used in `org.hibernate.criterion.Example` instances.

Comment: You might have to do a range query (ie, `>= *loval AND < *hival`).  Might not work, depending on types for the id.  You should be able to do this with a named query and JPQL - do you _have_ to use the `Criteria` API for this?

Comment: i found this SO question & answer. did the trick ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120852/hibernate-criteria-problem-with-composite-key

Comment: Anybody else needing this functionality check out [SO][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120852/hibernate-criteria-problem-with-composite-key